# How to exclude param from route matches with Regex in React Router DOM?

Tags: regex, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My goal is to have routes like this

/confirm/resend : *Shows resend form*

/confirm/31k41k2k12kl3lk : *Checks for token and redirects*

/confirm : *Shows form*

My route file looks like this

```
<Route path="/auth/confirm/resend" component={component.Confirm} />
<Route exact path="/auth/confirm/:token(?!(resend))?" component={component.Confirm} />
```

Problem is that `:token(?!(resend))?` this part does not work.

I'm trying to match /as12k and /1231jj1 here but not /resend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Switch` for rendering the first route that it encounters

```js
const Router = ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter;
const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
const Switch = ReactRouterDOM.Switch;

const Confirm = ()=><div>Confirm</div>;

const Resend = ()=><div>Resend</div>

const Token = ()=><div>Token</div>

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <p>Main App</p>
          <Link to="/confirm">Confirm </Link>
          <Link to="/confirm/resend">Resend </Link>
          <Link to="/confirm/123">Token </Link>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/confirm/resend" component={Resend} />
            <Route path="/confirm/:token" component={Token} />
            <Route path="/confirm" component={Confirm} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.2.0/react-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/4.2.2/react-router-dom.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch

Comment: Thanks :) Switch works. I cannot upvote. My rep is < 15

Comment: @David That's okay. Happy to Help